# Why does the RegExr tool and python re module not match my string?

Tags: python, regex, module

Why does my pattern from the RegExr online tool not match the same way with pythons re module? I use the same pattern from RegExr for the pattern argument in re.search() and re.match()

Here is my test string: "c  4:4  sd:4 31:3"

This is what RegExr online tool outputs: ['4:4', '31:3']

pattern_match.py is my python script

```
import re

#helper function
def displaymatch(match):
    if match is None:
       return None
    return '<Match: %r, groups=%r>' % (match.group(), match.groups())


user_input = raw_input("enter <number>:<number> ")
regex_pattern = r'[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
is_match = re.match(regex_pattern, user_input)
is_search = re.search(regex_pattern, user_input)

print "match function " + str(is_match)
print "search function " + str(is_search)

print(displaymatch(is_search))
```

Comment: Please paste your Python code exactly (related to `re` only part would be enough).

Comment: `search` will find the first match and return

Comment: thanks, that makes sense to me now. But how would I return all matches?

Comment: you are using `g` flag in regex..see **[here](https://regex101.com/r/mU6pQ5/1)** without `g` flag

Comment: `print(re.findall(regex_pattern, user_input))`

Answer (score 1):

The `groups()` method won't do you much good since there are no [capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) in your pattern and`group()` does not help that much as [`match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) (matches from the beginning) and [`search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) (matches anywhere) produce the first match only anyway. [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will return a list of all non-overlapping matching substrings:

```
> import re

> print re.findall(r'[0-9]+:[0-9]+', 'c 4:4 sd:4 31:3')
['4:4', '31:3']
```

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto

Answer (score 0):

i) In regex site, you are enabling `g` flag. So it is finding all the matches. See it **[here](https://regex101.com/r/mU6pQ5/1)** without `g` flag.

ii) `re.match` returns `None` because it finds match only in starting of the string.

iii) `re.search` will find the first match and return. So you get `4:4`.

iv) You need to use `re.findall(regex_pattern, user_input)` to find all matches.